# how to use tcpdump to capture packets with "ACK" flag set

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I want to capture packets with `ACK` flag set using tcpdump
including `SYN/ACK`, data packet and ACK packets
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the manual,

```
tcpdump 'tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-ack) != 0'
```

should do the trick